# Cannot connect pages from top nav menu

Tags: html

I am currently having problems connecting my top nav menu to each page.

I only stay on the Home tab and can't get to: about page, portfolio page or contact page.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#index" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#About">About</a>
  <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I upgraaded readability + removed unnecesary quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your link tags for each page have an href value that includes an anchor '#' tag. This is meant to reference something on the current html page. (not another page). You should supply the relative path to each page in the href:

```
<a href="/about.html">About</a>
```

Depending on what directory your files are in, you can do this for each page.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. I am working locally on my workstation so that was the difference. I also forgot to add the .html to each one. Thanks again!